# AdMob EU Consent Error: consent form can be used with custom provider selection only

Tags: android, admob

I am the Google consent SDK for android and I have followed all the steps listed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent). When I load the form I get this error in the `onConsentFormError` :

**consent form can be used with custom provider selection only.**

I have selected commonly used set of ad technology providers on AdMob console

[image]

So my questions are:

**1. For this option, do I need to take consent from user?** According to documentation on Google Developers site:

> Important: The Google-rendered consent form is not supported if any of
>   your publisher IDs use the commonly used set of ad technology
>   providers. Attempting to load the Google-rendered consent form will
>   always fail in this case.

So is it possible I'm getting this error because of the above limitation?

**2. If I have to take consent what to do about it in this case?** Should I show my own custom consent dialog or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am too working on this GDPR mess today and managed to get that Google-rendered form shown, like this:

[image]

According to my so far understanding, the only case you can make use of Google-rendered form is:

1. Use ***Custom set of ad technology providers***
2. And do NOT use ***mediation***

Otherwise you would need to render a dialog by yourself to ask for consent, which I decided not to, because according to my feeling most end users would go for negative choice while dealing with AD related questions, therefore I feel directly setting to Non-Personalized AD is in some level better than bothering user with a massive text and non-cancelable dialog.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot, I've been looking around the internet for this for a couple of hours now.

Comment: I still get the "consent form can be used with custom provider selection only". I am using 1. Custom set of ad technology providers and 2. And NOT using mediation. I've followed ZhouX's recommendation, and do not get the desired Google-rendered form. Why? I have read and followed https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

Comment: @TomV, it does have some delay, in my case, after I finished setup in admob console, it kept the same error until like 30 mins later.

Comment: @ZhouX, Thanks. It does have some delay (2 hrs in my case) and form is working now.

Comment: @TomV, just a heads up, adding com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library will silently append android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission into your manifest during build time, you may need to explicitly remove it if your previous version doesn't have it.

Comment: But, what are the 12 ads providers I should choose?

Comment: @ZhouX does the dialog show all the AdTechnology providers you've selected in the admob settings ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select at max 12 providers in EU user consent of AdMob. You can read more about it on [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-ios/issues/7) on GitHub thread.

[image]

You can pick this 12 out of 600 for start and tweak them for more revenue

- Google |   | https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/partner-sites/
- Aarki | http://corp.aarki.com/privacy
- Adobe Advertising Cloud | https://www.adobe.com/privacy/general-data-protection-regulation.html
- Amazon | https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201909010
- AppLovin Corp.  https://www.applovin.com/privacy
- AppNexus https://www.appnexus.com/en/company/platform-privacy-policy
- Dentsu Aegis Network  http://www.dentsu.com/termsofuse/data_policy.html
- eBay  https://www.ebay.com/help/policies/member-behaviour-policies/user-privacy-notice-privacy-policy?id=4260#section12
- Facebook | https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/update
- Interpublic Group | https://www.interpublic.com/privacy-notice
- Omnicom Media Group |https://www.omnicommediagroup.com/disclaimer.htm
- Smaato |https://www.smaato.com/privacy/

Comment: it says "The Consent SDK does not impose a limit on the number of ad technology providers a publisher chooses to enable." at the bottom of this page https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent so how come some people are saying only 12 can be picked ?

Comment: this limit of only 12 providers has been removed on version 1.0.5, you can check it on the changelog: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android/blob/master/ChangeLog.md

Comment: does anyone know about including the admob consent SDK in our apps privacy policy since it uses apache license 2.0 ?

Comment: @Marco do you know why it states on the docs  "One option is to use the Consent SDK to present a Google-rendered consent form to your users. The consent form displays a list of the ad technology providers you've selected in the AdMob UI.

The other option is to use the Consent SDK to dynamically retrieve the full list of ad technology providers from AdMob, as explained in publisher-managed consent collection. However, in this case you'll need to determine how the list of providers should be made available to your users and present your own consent form to your users."   whats the difference?

Answer (score 1):

So actually if the Number of adProviders are more than 11 then we cant use Admob consent form..So either we have to Choose only 12 custom adProviders or create our own custom dialog..Or use some kind of library which does the same...

U can Use This Simple Library for Generating Custom Consent Form if needed which simplifies the things

https://github.com/saiakhil90/ConsentDialog

Answer (score 0):

Your option is wrong, to use consent sdk you must choose option "Custom set..." and choose 12 or below, because the sdk not support more than 12 providers. Read more https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

Comment: But I don't want to use custom set of options, what to do in that case?

Comment: @IffatFatima build your own

Comment: @DzungPV I think they might have changed it to more than 12 ? as it states here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent , "The Consent SDK does not impose a limit on the number of ad technology providers a publisher chooses to enable." ??